# Pundit policy with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I am facing a problem where **limit** is overridden by the gem kaminari.
I know **page** overrides **limit** but can't find any other solution to my problem.

**Problem:**

My policy scope:

```
def resolve
  scope.limit(5)
end
```

When I call

```
users = policy_scope(User)
user.count # returns 5 (thats what I want)
```

but when I use policy_scope with kaminari

```
users = policy_scope(User).page(1)
user.count # returns 100 (not what I want, I want pagination to happen to 5 users that the policy returns)
```

Has anyone faced the same problem and found any work around?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the page method is generated here: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/blob/69f0160b174ab71c4125d6c4310933864d555648/kaminari-activerecord/lib/kaminari/activerecord/active_record_model_extension.rb

You could patch it, but I'd recommend leaving the original `page` method in
place and creating a new method for for your specific purpose. If you're OK
with calling it `page_with_policy` this should work:

```
module Kaminari
  module ActiveRecordModelExtension
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      include Kaminari::ConfigurationMethods

      # Fetch the values at the specified page number
      #   Model.page(5)
      eval <<-RUBY, nil, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
        def self.page_with_policy(num = nil)
          per_page = policy_scope(User).count
          limit(per_page).offset(per_page * ((num = num.to_i - 1) < 0 ? 0 : num)).extending do
            include Kaminari::ActiveRecordRelationMethods
            include Kaminari::PageScopeMethods
          end
        end
      RUBY
    end
  end
end
```

Add that to `lib/kaminari/activerecord/active_record_model_extension.rb` (create
those directories if they don't exist) and add some documentation to explain why you're
patching it (future developers will thank you).

Also, you may have to include the `pundit` helper in that file in order to be able to use the `policy_scope` method.